# Two identical consumers, but only one of them received the message, the other one didn't. How to solve this?

Tags: rabbitmq

Two identical consumers, but only one of them received the message, the other one didn't. How to solve this?After trying to send messages multiple times, I found that each consumer can receive messages, but the same message is only consumed by one consumer.

Consumer
@Component
public class RabbitMQListener {

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "manager.terminal")
public void terminalMessage(Message message, Channel channel) throws IOException {
    String s = new String(message.getBody());
    System.out.println("terminal message====："+ s);
}

@RabbitListener(queues = "manager.node")
public void nodeMessage(Message message, Channel channel) throws IOException {
    String s = new String(message.getBody());
    System.out.println("node message====："+ s);
}
```

}

Producer
@Configuration
public class rabbitMQConfig {

```
@Autowired
private RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin;
@Bean
public FanoutExchange managerFanoutExchange() {
    return new FanoutExchange("manager.fanout");
}
@Bean
public Queue clientManagerQueue() {
    return new Queue("manager.terminal");
}
@Bean
public Queue nodeManagerQueue() {
    return new Queue("manager.node");
}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    rabbitAdmin.declareBinding(BindingBuilder.bind(clientManagerQueue()).to(managerFanoutExchange()));
    rabbitAdmin.declareBinding(BindingBuilder.bind(nodeManagerQueue()).to(managerFanoutExchange()));
}

@Bean
public RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin = new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
    rabbitAdmin.setAutoStartup(true);
    return rabbitAdmin;
}

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate createRabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate();
    rabbitTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setMandatory(true);
    rabbitTemplate.setConfirmCallback(new RabbitTemplate.ConfirmCallback() {
        @Override
        public void confirm(CorrelationData correlationData, boolean ack, String cause) {
        }
    });
    rabbitTemplate.setReturnCallback((message, replyCode, replyText, exchange, routingKey) -> {
    });

    return rabbitTemplate;
}
```

}

@Service
public class MessagePublisher {

```
private final AmqpTemplate rabbitTemplate;

public MessagePublisher(AmqpTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
    this.rabbitTemplate = rabbitTemplate;
}

public void publishMessage() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String message = "Message at " + dateFormat.format(new Date());
    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("manager.fanout", "", "message:"+message);
}
```

}

Both consumers received messages from two queues

Comment: _Two identical consumers_ If they are truly identical, then from the server's perspective, they are **the same consumer**.  And of course a consumer will only see a message once...

Comment: If it's point to point messaging pattern, meaning use queues, then only one of the many consumers will get the message. If your requirement is that all consumers get a copy of the published message, then you will need to use publish - subscribe messaging pattern.